# HTTP 407 when trying to git clone from ghithub

Tags: git, github, proxy

I am unable to "git clone" from github behind my corporate firewall.  I have been troubleshooting this for a long time and have eliminated everything I can think of.  I have troubleshooted with our local firewall admin and I AM able to use git when using a local test firewall without our global policies.  I am trying to figure out how the production firewall even knows that I am using git and would like to somehow change my git "personality".  My firewall admin believes this is unintentional but the bureaucracy for addressing it wouldn't be feasible.

details on attemps with the prod firewall:

- I am able to visit github with a browser wget and curl. I can
  download the zip packages or individual files
- I have the proxy and authentication setup properly via `git config --global http(s).proxy`
  (confirmed with test on local firewall)
- I have tried alternate user agents via `git config --global http(s).useragent`

Looking for any other ideas on how to get git working via our production firewall

Comment: Run `curl -v` against GitHub and run your clone with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and compare the authentication headers to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

With my own corporate firewall, I only had 407 error message because of the NTLM proxy.

That is why:

- I use only `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` (and `NO_PROXY`) environment vzraible (they are respected by Git, and useful outside of Git: I do not ser `http.proxy` Git settings)
- I use an intermediate locally run proxy called **`px`** ([`genotrance/px`](https://github.com/genotrance/px)), which then knows how to speak to the corporate NTLM proxy.

My `HTTP(S)_PROXY` then becomes: `http://127.0.0.1:3128`.
No need to specify username/password. And it just works.